# UIPickerview's subviews count is always 3 in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, ios6.1

I just started to migrate to iOS 7 and found several issues concerning UIPickerView in my app.
And the reason is that I used the subviews of UIPickerView to customize it's background and style. I am logging the subviews count of UIpickerview and it's always is 3:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
 {
   return 1;
 }

 -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
   return 22;
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
   UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
   label.frame = CGRectMake(152, 3,100, 16);
   label.text = @"test";
   NSLog(@"count is %i",_pickerView.subviews.count);
   return label;
}
```

I iOS 6.1, the count is always 9.

Edit 1:
Another difference:
The bellow code crashes on iOS 7 and works without any problems on iOS 6.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{ 
   UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
   label.frame = CGRectMake(152, 3,100, 16);
   label.text = @"test";

   if(row > 3){
     UIView* view = [pickerView viewForRow:3 forComponent:0]; // crash in iOS 7
   }

    NSLog(@"count is %i",_pickerView.subviews.count);
    return label;
}
```

Edit 2: 
_pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;

has not any affection on iOS 7.

Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: Internal structure of picker view is just a implementation detail, that can vary in different OS versions. You should not depend on that anyway

Comment: What error message you get on crash? I ran sample project with your code and it worked fine

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:                                             (Scroll the picker and it will crash)

Comment: I updated my question, please see the change.